# A continuous function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, vector-analysis

Good day.

Is $\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})-\exp\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1{}}\right)\right)$ continuous function in all $\mathbb{R^2}$? Wolfram indicates affirmative, but the points in that the tangent function is undefined?

Thanks.

Comment: A little bit fuzzy: Every function involved is continuous, so the function is continuous (where it is defined). However, you do not mention where the function is defined on.

Comment: The argument of the tangent is positive and $\le 1$, hence it never can be equal $\frac\pi 2+k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a continuous function, since it was obtaind from continuous functions using composition and arithmetic operations. The fact that it is undefind at certain points is not relevant. The function$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&\dfrac1x\end{array}$$is continuous, although it is undefined at $0$.